# Упрощенные регулярные выражения или что-то этого другое

Tags: java, c++, python, библиотеки

Есть такой нестандартный вопрос. Скажем так, нужна какая-нибудь библиотека или метод, принцип для создания, скажем так, чат бота. Есть входная строка и есть база готовых шаблонов в котором определены заготовки. Входной текст сравнивается с базой шаблонов и если есть совпадения, то возвращает какой-нибудь результат.

Например, входная строка "Привет, как дела?"

В базе есть такие шаблоны

```
[
    {id: 0, text: "Привет, как дела?"},
    {id: 1, text: "Здравствуй, как дела?"},
    {id: 2, text: "Братан, ты как?"},
    {id: 3, text: "Добрый день, как вы?"},
    {id: 4, text: "Здарова, как жизнь?"}
    ...
]
```

После сравнения входной строки мы должны получить `{id: 1}`, но конечно же это достаточно просто реализовать. Если посмотреть 5 записей в базе почти похожи и их можно было бы как-то объединить и вместо текста написать какую `regex` проверку, чтобы мы получали входной текст и проверяли по записям базы пока регулярное выражение не будет `true`. Но что если нужно создать 10,000 шаблонов? Писать в этом случае регулярные выражения было бы не очень.

Вот мне и нужно сделать что-то на подобии более упрощенных регулярных выражений. Например, если кто знаком с сервисом iii.ru, то там такая функция реализована, но говорят, что у них все работает на ии, а мне как-бы создать ии не под силу. Есть так же сайт Flow.ai где это все дело очень просто делается, не знаю как у них реализовано.

Например, я хочу вот так

Есть шаблон: `{Привет, Добрый день, Здравствуй, Хеллов}, как [ {у вас, у тебя, ты},[не обязательно]] [{дела, жизнь, всё}, [не обязательно]]?`

и этот шаблон подходит для таких строк:

- Привет, как дела?
- Привет, как ты?
- Привет, как жизнь?
- Добрый день, как у вас дела?
- Здравствуй, как жизнь?

  и т.д.

Думаю, недостаточно хорошо объяснил суть вопроса, но надеюсь кто нибудь поймет и сможет чем-то помочь.

Comment: Ну вообще человеческий язык это не такая простая штука, чтобы все вопросы и ответы можно было бы предвидеть. А что если напишут сокращенно или с ошибкой? Но, впринципе, вам может подойти контейнер map. В качестве ключей можете указать входные фразы, а ответы - как полезую информацию. Поиск происходит быстро благодаря древовидной структуре.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду дополнительные литералы выводимые при наборе текста в смс сообщении, которые автоматически подставляют варианты продолжения? Если да, то как и сказали выше -> создайте фабрику таких фраз, тот же массив подойдет, проверяйте на совпадение слов list.contains(from_value) и выводите спокойно в варианты ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для наибольшей скорости сравнение строк нужно перевести в сравнение более коротких чисел. Каждое слово можно представить определённым числом, которое можно расчитать на основе символов этого слова. Необходимо также, чтобы бот хорошо распознавал смысл введенных фраз и находил похожие в базе. Например, «Привет!», «Здарова!», «Йо!» имеют одинаковый смысл. Можно перевести все подобные вопросы в векторном представлении, когда слова/вопросы с одинаковым смыслом будут находиться близко к друг-другу на координатной плоскости/пространстве. Например:

```
{
    {a:"Йо", id:(1 1)}
    {a:"Привет", id:(1 2)}
    {a:"Здарова", id: (2 1)}
    {a:"Пока", id:(340 400)}
}
```

Ввод пользователя разделям на слова, высчитываем координаты, вектор вопроса, и находим ближайшее похожее по смыслу, после чего вынимаем ответ. То есть каждая строка представляется вектором в пространстве смысла. Это называется "векторным представлением текста" в пространстве смыслов.

Способы представления разнятся. Наиболее популярны модели word2vec и GloVe. Используя их, можно добиться более-менее нормальной работы бот-чата, но не идеально. Есть более совершенные модели, но тогда возникает ряд проблем:

Распределённые способы представления текста в векторе (вроде word2vec) используют статистику вероятности согласно гипотезе: “слова, которые встречаются в одинаковых окружениях, имеют близкие значения”. То есть загружается текст, анализируется, составляются вероятности и на их основе создаются вектора. Чем больше текста, тем больше слов, тем лучше анализ. Однако "смысл" текста в редких случаях расчитать трудно, модель из опытной резко превратится в необученую.

То есть по сути требуется обучение, но в итоге мы получаем всё же не слишком совершенный результат.

Если же совершенствовать такую модель, то она банально выродится в нейронную сеть.

Советую почитать:
Нечёткий поиск в тексте и словаре.
Коррекция ошибок в тексте, поисковые запросы.

В вашем случае нужен именно нечёткий поиск в тексте и словаре. Строки сравниваются через модель перестановок, находится между ними растояние и выбирается наиболее подходящая строка.

"Расстояние Дамерау-Левенштейна" — это именно то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Очень полезная информация, спасибо, но это не то что мне нужно, подправил вопрос

Comment: @HuffyGrams ответ остаётся тем же, лишь немного подправлю.